# file_get_contents() equivalent for Node.JS

Tags: node.js, curl, file-get-contents

I was wondering if there was any `file_get_contents()` equivalents in Node.JS modules or elsewhere. It has to lock the process until the download is finished, so the existing `request()` code in Node.js won't work. While it doesn't need to read into the string, the locking, synchronous nature is important.

If this doesn't exist, is using CURL via the OS module an efficient way of handling the same process?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Tell us what your goal is, not how you want to reach it.

Comment: Why do you think you have to lock the whole process?

Comment: If your requirement is locking the whole process, then NodeJS is definitely not the technology for you. Why not just use PHP? Then you can use `file_get_contents()` itself.

Comment: @BryanRoss: That's not a requirement, I'd say it's more like a lack of knowledge.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think in async just yet... an acquired taste type of thing maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's not. Do it asynchronously: Do stuff, and when the download completes and you've buffered it all into one place, emit an event or call a callback to do the work on the whole blob.

Comment: "buffered it all into one place" - sometimes you can also operate on a rechunked stream.

Comment: @KyleHotchkiss: Do you think you fully understand how node.js works? The evented and async patterns?

Comment: Never claimed to fully understand node.js. Don't think that as a requirement to experiment with it or to ask a question on SO. Coming from browser JS, there are still plenty of constraints to work on.

Comment: It's actually not hard to do: all of this is a few lines of code. But node doesn't let you stop the world while something happens: If there's something to do, node runs it. If not, it stops entirely while waiting. But you can usually do that by just not continuing until the network responds and the pieces have come together. sometimes working this way is a little like setting up dominoes then setting them all falling at once. But it works, and it frees up the process to do a LOT of other things while it waits.

Answer (score 25):

[`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) appears to do what you're asking. From the manual:

> ### fs.readFileSync(filename, [options])
>
> Synchronous version of `fs.readFile`. Returns the contents of the `filename`.
>
> If the `encoding` option is specified then this function returns a string. Otherwise it returns a buffer.

Comment: Sadly `fs.readFileSync()` does not work with a web url unlike `file_get_contents()`. I think OP is asking for a way to fetch external resource, not a local file.

Answer (score 22):

Nice for load some conf files on app start but its Sync !!!!

```
const fs = require('fs');
var contents = fs.readFileSync('inject.txt').toString();
```